# Double Daniell extension and limsup

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I$ be a non-negative linear function of $C_{00}(X)$ the space of continuous functions of compact support on a locally compact Hausdorff space X. Let $\bar{\bar{I}}$ be the Daniell extension of $I$ to $\mathcal{F}^+$ the space of functions from X to the extended non-negative real numbers and $(h_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{F}^+$. I need to show $$\bar{\bar{I}}(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}h_n)\leq\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bar{\bar{I}}(h_n)$$

I really have no idea how to proceed. Any tips are welcomed.

Side question: if anybody knows how to write double bars over letters without any side effect, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know much about Daniell integrals, but in the measure theory setting the reverse Fatou Lemma states that for a sequence $(h_n)$ that is dominated by a non-negative integrable function, we have $\limsup \int h_n \leq \int \limsup h_n$. There are also [examples](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/376360/258909) where the inequality is strict, and this would contradict your claim. Are you sure your inequality isn't supposed to be the other way around?

Comment: You are right! The link you gave indeed states a counter example to what I was trying to prove. I edited the question to ask for Fatou's Lemma in this general setting.